# Convert the location on GMSMapView to the screen's coordinate system

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, coordinate-systems

[image]

I'm trying to convert the location of the red drop pin from the GMSMapView to the coordinate system of its superview (the view of the UIViewController).

Basically, as you can see from the attached image, the pin's location is (170,275) with respect to the GMSMapView. However, I can't manage to get that value using the functionalities provided GoogleMaps SDK.

Here is what I tried:
Step 1, I have the GPS coordinates for the pin, and I convert it to the CGPoint using:

```
let pinLocation = mapView.projection.point(for: pinCoordinate)
```

The resulting pinLocation has huge magnitude (for example: (1614979.75, -1187222.25)) which doesn't correspond to the visible pin in the mapView.
Step 2, I convert the point's location between the coordinate systems of different views:

```
let pinLocationInView = mapView.convert(pinLocation, to: view) // view contains the mapView
```

And pinLocationInView has almost the same large magnitude as pinLocation. Clearly, this approach doesn't work as I expected.

Then, I tried to get the visible region of the mapView's projection, hoping to get the result by doing simple math:

```
let region = projection.visibleRegion()
let farLeft = projection.point(for: region.farLeft)
let xOffset = pinLocation.x - farLeft.x
let yOffset = pinLocation.y - farLeft.y
```

To my surprise, it doesn't work either. The reason is that the visible region is not what I actually see on the screen, and the farLeft is (0.0, 0.0)

After tons of research in GoogleMaps SDK documentation for iOS and similar questions in this site, I couldn't find any answer to my question.

Comment: swift or objective-?

Comment: Swift-3 and Google Maps SDK v2.3.3 for iOS.

Comment: You still need an answer for this?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes, I m in need to get answer of this. Can u guide ?

Answer (score 3):

Convert CGPoint to Lat Long

```
let topLeft = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
let firstSideLatLong = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: topLeft)
```

Convert Lat Long to CGPoint

```
let coordinate = CLLocation(latitude:40.712216, longitude:-74.22655)
let point = mapView.projection.point(for: coordinate)
```